# Relationship vs Multiplicity

Tags: database-design, uml, relationship

I've been looking everywhere but I couldn't find the difference between table relationships and multiplicities.

What's the main difference seeing that both of them can be one-many, many-one, and etc.
The only difference I noticed so far is that multiplicities are depicted in 1..* format, or am I wrong?

If we have a table User and User can own multiple Blogs, what's the relationship here and what's the multiplicity?

Comment: What's your definition of multiplicity? Do you mean in a UML sense? I'm pretty sure multiplicity is not a common phrase in relation to DB design

Comment: Think of multiplicity as minimum and maximum. 1.. is min 1 and max infinity. 1..1 is min 1 and max 1

Comment: @Liam yes we basically have diagram in UML sense with entities (SQL Tables) and are asked what are relationships and what are multiplicites. My question is what is the difference here between relationship and multiplicity.

Comment: @Striker but whats the relationship then?

Comment: The difference is relationship is the relation between 2 tables. There are only 4 types: one to many upto many to many. With multiplicity, you can have specific values such as 5..5 to 1.. that is table A can have 1 or more table Bs. Table B has exactly 5 table As

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two notations are related, but not the same.

The `1..*`, `0..*`  etcetera represent the multiplicity of *one end* of a relationship.  One-to-many is actually describing the multiplicities of both ends of a relationship; i.e "one-to-many" means `1..1` (or maybe `0..1`) at one end and `1..*` (or maybe `0..*`) at the other end.

And as, you can see, multiplicity notation allows you to express optional versus mandatory relationships ... which "one-to-many" doesn't cover.

---

> If we have a table User and User can own multiple Blogs, what's the relationship here and what's the multiplicity?

That would be described as one-to-many, but in UML you would express the relationship like this:

```
                BlogAuthorship

   -------- 1..1              0..* --------
   | User | <--------------------> | Blog |
   --------                        --------
```

which is also saying that:

- a Blog must have a exactly one User as author, and
- a User doesn't necessarily need to be an author of any Blog.